# could not checkout branch due untracked files

Tags: git

I am using git to manage my php project and I have 3 branches master, staging, development.

So I merged my new feature into the `master` branch but problem is that git refuses to switch back to development branch.

My .gitignore content:

```
config_enviroment.php
.htaccess
.idea
a013/app/tmp/*
smarty/smarty_templates_c/*
config_enviroment.php
```

So now I am on `master` 
when I type git status:

```
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

So far seems to be ok. But now I try to get back to work on development branch

```
git checkout development
error: The following untracked working tree giles would be overwritten by checkout:
    a013/app/Model/admin.php
    a013/app/Model/articles.php
    ....
Please move or remove them before you can swich branches.
Aborting
```

Question: why does git refuse to switch branch even if those files are tracked and my working directory is clean?

Answer (score 0):

The working directory is only clean in the sense that no files need to be committed: everything is either committed or ignored. But Git still protects you from data loss by refusing to do a checkout that would overwrite untracked files, regardless of their `.gitignore` status.

Comment: I've tried to remove remove gitignore file which would mean that `git status` should show all untracked files but none of files that git complains about is listed even without gitignore, which if I understand it correctly should be already tracked..

Comment: @insanebits `git status` doesn't necessarily show all the files, but then it should show the directory that those files reside in.

Answer (score 0):

Because you did make some changes in `a013/app/Model/admin.php` and in   `a013/app/Model/articles.php` that will be overwritten by the changes made in the branch that you are trying to move to (development).

You have the options:

- stash your changes with `git stash` and get those changes later by using `git stash pop`. Note that you my have conflits.
- commit your changes
- discard your changes with `git reset HEAD --hard` or `git checkout a013/app/Model/admin.php a013/app/Model/articles.php`